# What pattern can I use to write CRUD functionality?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, crud

I am writing a console application. CRUD functionality.I would like to try to apply the pattern. Is it possible to apply a "state" pattern? In the AddCustomer () method at the end, the call to the InputMenu () method, I do not think that this is correct.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataFunction dataFunction = new DataFunction();
        dataFunction.InputMenu();
    }

public void InputMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Add Customer? --- 1, Remove customer? --- 2, Show All Customer? --- 3");
            string _value = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (_value)
            {
                case "1":
                    AddCustomer();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    RemoveCustomer();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    ShowAllCustomers();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("You clicked an unknown letter");
                    break;
            }

public void AddCustomer()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Input Name");
            string _name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Input Adress");
            string _adress = Console.ReadLine();

            _dataContext.Customers.Add(
                new Customer
                {
                    Name = _name,
                    Adress = _adress
                });
            _dataContext.SaveChanges();

            InputMenu();
        }
```

I would like to remake the "InputMenu", is it possible to apply the state pattern?

Comment: If you have a working code and look for suggestions for improvement, I suggest you to repost your question to: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it'd be a good practice to place your business logic on a different layer, you could re-use the code if needed, for ie, exposing your logic on a RESTFul or GraphQL API. A very practical way is to use [Clean Architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html).

My point is, focus on your business core (Entities + Use Cases), follow the dependency rule, code your database access on a repository layer and, to gain some productivity, use an ORM (Entity Framework).

Comment: I would like to implement a start menu. And apply the State pattern. Is it possible to implement this simple example in theory?